# How to change the text direction of an element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

On Facebook, for example, if you have chosen the Arabic language for your keyboard, the textbox automatically gets RTL direction.

How can I implement this on my web application? I don't know the method or property used.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use the CSS `direction` property to achieve this:

```
input{
  direction: rtl;
}
```

**Update**

To change the direction of the text dynamically based on the user input you can check the first character of input to see if it meets a given criteria, in this case a regular expression.

```
$('input').keyup(function(){
    $this = $(this);
    if($this.val().length == 1)
    {
        var x =  new RegExp("[\x00-\x80]+"); // is ascii

        //alert(x.test($this.val()));

        var isAscii = x.test($this.val());

        if(isAscii)
        {
            $this.css("direction", "ltr");
        }
        else
        {
            $this.css("direction", "rtl");
        }
    }

});
```

This is a basic example that uses `ltr` direction for ascii text and `rtl` for everything else.

[Here's a working example.](http://jsfiddle.net/BSwN6/)

Comment: Thank you,
Yes I know , but the direction will be rtl allways.
what I want is when you write first character if it is english characters the input gets lrt direction and if you write arabic or Hebrew it changes automatically to rtl.

Comment: thanks . but have not working in all swap change lang on keyboard

Comment: This solution is very good. +1 ...! Jut is has a small problem. When I press `<space>`, this code thinks it is ascii and changes the direction to `ltr`. How can I fix it?

Comment: Does it work for other languages such as Korean and Japanese?

Answer (score 31):

In HTML5 you can simply do this:

```
<input type="text" dir="auto" />
```

this automatically change the direction of input base on first character.
Hope it helps.

NOTE:

Edited: People say that it does not work in IE11.

Comment: It's not supported in IE 11

Comment: this is very fine, but how can I come to know the text direction on the server side

Comment: There is also [`dirname` attribute](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#attr-fe-dirname) to send direction as separate field to server.
IE / Edge might not support it yet: https://www.w3.org/International/tests/repository/html5/the-dirname-attribute/results-dirname (stale but expected as long as they [don't support dir=auto](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/257854-microsoft-edge-developer/suggestions/10784463-support-dir-auto))

Answer (score 1):

it's best to detect text direction based on first character of the text. if the first one belongs to RTL language, then direction has to change.

example, a Persian text with English word in it.

> به معنای واقعی tired هستم

another example, an English paragraph might contain a Persian word but the whole text has to be in LTR.

> this word is used in different situations. the meaning of شیر is...

this function will check the first character typed in. if it belongs to a RTL language, then direction will change. This code supports all RTL languages.

```
function isRTL(str) {
  var letters = [];
  allRTL = new RegExp(
    "^[\u0590-\u05fe\u0600-۾܀-ݎݐ-ݾހ-\u07be߀-\u07fe\u0800-\u083e\u0840-\u085e\u08a0-\u08fe\u0900-ॾ]|\ud802[\udf60-\udf7e]+$"
  );
  var cursor = 1;
  for (var i = 0; i <= cursor; i++) {
    letters[i] = str.substring(i - 1, i);
    if(/\s/.test(letters[i])) {
      cursor++;
    }
    if (allRTL.test(letters[i])) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
var dir = $("input[type=text]");
dir.keyup(function(e) {
  if (isRTL(dir.val())) {
    $(this).css("direction", "rtl");
  } else {
    $(this).css("direction", "ltr");
  }
});
```

for more info visit this [codepen](https://codepen.io/hadifarnoud/pen/rmdxWe).

Answer (score 1):

For input element you can use Unicode intrinsic direction

```
input {
    text-align: start;
    unicode-bidi: plaintext;
}
```

Of course, it works with other elements such as div with `contenteditable` as true as mentioned by comments.

Comment: apparently, you can use it on any element.

Answer (score -1):

> **DISCLAIMER** as stated by [@bool3max](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5447136/bool3max): Many languages utilize Unicode characters and are written
>   LTR. Your function sets `direction: rtl` for all non-ASCII characters,
>   which isn't desired.

I have found also a [Pen](https://codepen.io/siamak/pen/rAmBb) that does exactly the same without Regex. I have tweaked the code a bit to be compatible with multiple input fields and textareas.
It serves the purpose of using it between; for example; EN and AR languages.

```
$('input[type="text"], textarea').each(function () {
    $(this).on('input keyup keypress', function () {
      if (isUnicode($(this).val())) {
        $(this).css('direction', 'rtl');
      } else {
        $(this).css('direction', 'ltr');
      }
    });
  });

  function isUnicode(str) {
    var letters = [];
    for (var i = 0; i <= str.length; i++) {
      letters[i] = str.substring((i - 1), i);
      if (letters[i].charCodeAt() > 255) { return true; }
    }
    return false;
  }
```

Comment: *Many* languages utilize Unicode characters and are written LTR. Your function sets `direction: rtl` for all non-ASCII characters, which isn't desired.