# Detect if user is using browser with RTL language

Tags: javascript, right-to-left, http-accept-language

How can I detect in my webpage using javascript if the user is using a browser with RTL language? For example Arabic. I want to provide a different layout for them.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript: how to check if character is RTL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12006095/javascript-how-to-check-if-character-is-rtl)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I might be missing something, but since it's your webpage/server that ultimately decides whether to display/send Arabic text or not can't you use the browser language preference to also provide a different layout?

[JavaScript for detecting browser language preference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043339/javascript-for-detecting-browser-language-preference)

Comment: Yeah, client info on server side is the best way, Most i18n/l10n libs/framworks, provide a away to check if a specific language is RTL or not.