# How can I automatically set text direction based on input text language?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bidi

In Google plus (and a lot of other places), when I want to post something, when I type it in Persian, which is a right-to-left language, text direction is automatically set to **rtl** and `text-alignment:right`, and when I start to type in English it changes automatically to **ltr** and `text-alignment:left`. How can I have such functionality? Is this anything with HTML5 or Javascript? What clues should I follow?

Thanks in advance

Comment: **this link is very good for you :** 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7770235/change-text-direction-of-textbox-automatically/19449332#19449332

Comment: Thank you @ErfanSafarpoor, This has been solved long ago BTW ;)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Add `dir=auto` to your input elements:

> Use dir="auto" on forms and inserted text in order to automatically detect the direction of content supplied at run-time.

https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-dir#quickanswer

Comment: Also you may need to add "text-align:justify" to style in order to get right alignment.

Comment: Wow, is it that easy?

Answer (score 12):

I was having issue with `dir=auto` sometimes not working.

After digging CSS I found

```
#container > * {
    text-align: start;
    unicode-bidi: plaintext;
}
```

More flexible and universal

Answer (score 9):

I wrote a JQuery code to do this. Just add class "checkRTL" to the element you want to set its direction.

```
var rtlChar = /[\u0590-\u083F]|[\u08A0-\u08FF]|[\uFB1D-\uFDFF]|[\uFE70-\uFEFF]/mg;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.checkRTL').keyup(function(){
        var isRTL = this.value.match(rtlChar);
        if(isRTL !== null) {
            this.style.direction = 'rtl';
         }
         else {
            this.style.direction = 'ltr';
         }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

There's also Twitter's library, which may help:

https://github.com/twitter/RTLtextarea

Answer (score 4):

Add `dir="auto"` to your element and then use `window.getComputedStyle(element).getPropertyValue('direction')`

Example:

```
<div id="foo" dir="auto">نے والے ہیں۔<div>

// returns rtl
window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('foo')).getPropertyValue('direction')
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('foo')).getPropertyValue('direction')
```

```html
<div class="" id="foo">

<div class="English">this is test message</div>
<div class="Persian">این یک پیام تستی است</div>
<div class="Persian-English">test برای حالت فارسی</div>

</div>
```

In Persian, if first sentence starts with an English word like last ***div***,  the whole text is placed in LTR mode

Answer (score 2):

1. list the right to left languages typical characters
2. detect them on the fly (usual js events)
3. change css classes accordingly

Or follow this link:

http://www.i18nguy.com/temp/rtl.html

Comment: Well, As you suggested, I detect characters using RegExp like `ltrChars : 'A-Za-z\u00C0-\u00D6 .....`, and change CSS classes whenever they are needed.