# How to save text direction default in web sites?

Tags: text, web, right-to-left, direction, bidi

I wonder if there a way to save text direction default- right to left (RTL) or vise versa (left to right-LTR) in different web pages. So when i open specific web site the text direction will be automatically LTR or RTL. I use google chrome so i tried to search in the properties and didn't find any option to save text direction default. I red [change text direction of textbox automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7770235/change-text-direction-of-textbox-automatically/19449332#19449332) and [How can I automatically set text direction based on input text language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15441898/how-can-i-automatically-set-text-direction-based-on-input-text-language) and other questions and search in my windows xp Language preference but didn't find what i'm looking for. 
Thanks in advance for any help.

UPDATE:

I'm using a program called "Lang Over 5" that changed text orientation using "F10" button. But i can't save default text orientation in web sites with it.

Answer (score 0):

It likely cannot be done for different webpages/sites unless someone has created an add-on module that I'm unaware of. Here are two options that you can do, however:

1) Use two different browsers, set each to the proper language settings that you want.

2) If you are set on using Chrome for both, you may be able to run multiple instances as is shown here: http://blog.buddywork.com/post/15839021578/how-to-run-multiple-instances-of-chrome