# Magento : How change theme direction by language

Tags: php, magento

Example: if I use arabic language the text field direction will be rtl and if I want to write a new text and I switch to the English language the direction inside the text field (`text-align: left) will be ltr automatically

i have two language in my site.

one is `English`, and the second is `Arabic`.

So, when i click in Arabic languse site, i need to change direction of theme from LTR to Rtl,
and when click English languge, i need to change direction to LTR.

my site :-

http://p1.b7d.com/magento/meghzal/index.php/

thank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here would like to suggest to make individual css for your Arabic store to change Direction
Add below add into you new `style.css`

```
direction:rtl
```

to your input in new css

Also you can use by javascript

[How to Change CSS direction property of the input field automaticly if the user can use an language rtl or ltr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6777118/how-to-change-css-direction-property-of-the-input-field-automaticly-if-the-user)

**Edit**

Add CSS from `layout.xml` or `local.xml`

```
<default>
  <reference name="head">   
     <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/arstyles.css</name>/action>
  </reference>
</default>
```

hope this will sure help you.

Comment: ok but how can i define the direction and make for it the own style

Comment: you have to create own style.css and assign thie style folder to your store by admin configuration, you can change from `system-> configuration-> design -> skin` folder to create folder for store and put your style.css in it

Comment: yes i am talking about custom store. select your store from left drop down in sytem configuration.it would be glad for me if u will acpt my answer

Comment: yourmagento\skin\frontend\default\yourskin\css\style.css name should be same style.css because it will effect automatically from xml.pls dont change name from `style.css` to `style_ar.css`

Comment: iam go to  `system-> configuration-> design -> skin (Images / CSS)` and write `http://p1.b7d.com/magento/meghzal/skin/frontend/breeze/default/css/arstyles.css` on it but not work why ???

Comment: pls add `breeze` in your package and add css to style.css

Comment: i add in  `Current Package Name` this `breeze`

Comment: so what can i do for add arstyle.css for arabic store

Comment: if you want to add arstyle.css to only your arabic store. create you own skin folder add all default css and images in skin's relavent folder and use my updated code to include css from local.xml or layour.xml of your store only

Comment: @kamgfx,glad to help you.